# How to count 1 option selected in dropdown from different rows added and display in textbox?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

**How to count 1 option selected in dropdown from different rows and display count in textbox?**

I would like to count total value `casualties` of different rows and display count of total value `casualties` in textbox id `injury`.

Codes for dropdownlist && textbox && add row:

```html
<select name="type" id="dd">
<option>Select a Type</option>
<option value="casualties">Casualties</option>
<option value="notcasualties">Not Casualties</option>
</select>
</select>

<label>Casualties:</label><input type="text" id="injury">

<btn><input type="button" value="addrow" onclick="addrow('dataTable2')" /></btn>
```

This codes are only able to display count = 1 in textbox id `injury` for the first row but not the added rows. I would like to total up count of value `casualties` after different rows are added. Could anyone help me.

```
$('#dd').change(function(){ 
        var count = $('#dd option:selected').length;
        $('.injury').val(count); 
        });
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not sure I get this. It looks like #dd only allows you to select 1 option, so the length of casualties is always either 1 or 0.

In which instance will there be more than 1? Do you have multiple selects called #dd?

Comment: Hi @AndreaOlivato, I've edited and added in the codes for add row function for length of casualties to be more than 1. Thanks!

Comment: please diplay the code of table display and also you did not check all rows from the table

Comment: Can be done on `onclick` event of the button

Comment: Hi @LDS, i don't really get what it means by check all rows from the table.

Comment: you ask count total value casualties of different rows .In loop you can get the value of casualties from each row.You did not show this code

Comment: oh I see, thanks @LDS however, I only used function addRow (dataTable2) code for new rows, hence, I don't have other codes for each row.

Comment: Where is the display function to display the rows in html

Comment: Hi @VivekBhardwaj,  I tried function dropdown() { $('#dd').change(function (){ //choice in dropdown var count = $('#dd option:selected').length; $('.injury').val(count, count1); //display in tb }); } and <btn><INPUT type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow('dataTable2'); dropdown();" /></btn> but it didn't work. Is there any suggestions to use onclick event button?

Comment: @LDS, sorry I'm quite new to this, I've updated the codes before `<select>`, not sure if it is the display, `table id="dataTable2"`, all the way at the top

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `onchange="select($(this).val())"` in `select` tag and following function in `script`

```
function select(value){
    if(value==="casualties"){
        $("#injury").val(parseInt($("#injury").val())+1);
    }
    else{
        $("#injury").val(parseInt($("#injury").val())-1);
        if($("#injury").val()<0)
            $("#injury").val("0");
    }
}
```

and remove

```
$('#dd').change(function(){ 
    var count = $('#dd option:selected').length;
    $('.injury').val(count); 
    });
```

Comment: Above code may help you but a little coding have to do yourself

Comment: thanks but it doesn't pop the count, 'NaN' appeared in the textbox instead.

Comment: `value="0"` in `input` tag where `id` is `injury`

Comment: Alright thank you so much for your help @VivekBhardwaj, greatly appreciate it. I will continue trying!

Answer (score 0):

I made some changes that full fill your purpose

```html
<html>
<head><title>table example</title></head>
<body>
    <table id="dataTable2">
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <TH>Admin No/Staff ID:</TH>
            <TH>Name:</TH>
            <TH>Contact No:</TH>
            <TH>Types of People Involved:</TH>
        </TR>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]"></td>
            <TD><input type="text" name="id[]" id="id" /></TD>
            <TD><input type="text" name="names[]" id="names"></TD>
            <TD><input type="text" name="contacts[]" id="contacts" /> </TD>
            <TD>
                <select name="type" id="dd" class="selectpicker" data-style="select-with-transition" title="News Type" data-size="7" onchange="show()">
                    <option value="">Select a Type</option>
                    <option value="casualties" class="casualties-element">Casualties</option>
                    <option value="ncasualties">Non-Casualties</option>
                    <option value="witness">Witness</option>
                </select>
            </TD>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <p>
        <INPUT type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow()" />
    </p>
    <table id="dataTable1" style="cellpadding:20px;">
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <TH>Admin No/Staff ID:</TH>
            <TH>Name:</TH>
            <TH>Contact No:</TH>
            <TH>Types of People Involved:</TH>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <p>
    <label>No. of Casualties:</label>
    <input type="text" name="injury" id="injury" class="injury span2" onClick="show();">

      
    </p>
        <script>
            var count = 0;
            function addRow() {
                alert("test");
                var table1 = document.getElementById('dataTable1');
                var table = document.getElementById('dataTable2');
                var did = document.getElementById('id').value;
                var dname = document.getElementById('names').value;
                var dcontact = document.getElementById('contacts').value;
                var dddl = document.getElementById('dd');
              
                var ddlvalue = dddl.options[dddl.selectedIndex].value;
                if (ddlvalue == 'casualties') { count++; }
                document.getElementById('injury').value = count;
                var rowCount = table.rows.length;
                //var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
                var row = table1.insertRow(1);

                var colCount = table.rows[1].cells.length;
                
                for (var i = 0; i < colCount; i++) {

                    var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
                    
                    //newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[1].cells[i].innerHTML;
                    //alert(newcell.childNodes);
                    switch (i) {
                        case 0:
                            newcell.innerHTML = did;
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            newcell.innerHTML = dname;
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            newcell.innerHTML = dcontact;
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            newcell.innerHTML = ddlvalue;
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        </script>
</body>
</html>
```